# IOException on writing a file to Hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, ioexception

I'm working on a program that takes gps data from a mqtt broker and loads it into the hadoop cluster. On trying to write the data to hdfs, I'm getting and IOException. The following is the full stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: callId, status; Host Details : local host is: "quickstart.cloudera/192.168.25.170"; destination host is: "quickstart.cloudera":8020; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:765)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:184)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.<init>(DFSOutputStream.java:1250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1021)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:806)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:675)
    at com.mqttHadoopLoader.hadoop.MqttLoader.HdfsWriter.writeToHdfs(HdfsWriter.java:19)
    at com.mqttHadoopLoader.hadoop.MqttLoader.MqttDataLoader.messageArrived(MqttDataLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.handleMessage(CommsCallback.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.run(CommsCallback.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: callId, status
    at com.google.protobuf.UninitializedMessageException.asInvalidProtocolBufferException(UninitializedMessageException.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcPayloadHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto$Builder.buildParsed(RpcPayloadHeaderProtos.java:1094)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcPayloadHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto$Builder.access$1300(RpcPayloadHeaderProtos.java:1028)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcPayloadHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.parseDelimitedFrom(RpcPayloadHeaderProtos.java:986)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:781)
```

It seems like the error is occurring when I try to create the OutputStream but it's difficult to say because my eclipse debugger isn't working correctly (it says that it cannot connect to the VM and I've tried a multitude of fixes posted here on stackoverflow). Here is my code for my HdfsWriter:

```
String destFile = "hdfs://127.0.0.0.1:8020/gpsData/output/gps_data.txt";
 //Note *this is just a placeholder IP address for the purpose of this post. I do have the fully correct IP address for the program. 

    public void writeToHdfs(String gpsInfo) {
        try {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            System.out.println("Connecting to -- " + conf.get("fs.defaultFS"));

            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(destFile), conf);
            System.out.println(fs.getUri());

            // Error seems to occur here
            OutputStream outStream = fs.create(new Path(destFile));

            byte[] messageByt = gpsInfo.getBytes();
            outStream.write(messageByt);
            outStream.close();

            System.out.println(destFile + " copied to HDFS");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the mqtt method that calls for the HdfsWriter:

```
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message)
        throws Exception {
            System.out.println(message);
            HdfsWriter hdfsWriter = new HdfsWriter();
            hdfsWriter.writeToHdfs(message.toString());
    }
```

I'm still really new to hadoop so any and all help would be great.

**UPDATE**
I've got my debug working and can definitively tell you that the error occurs whenever I try to call a FileSystem method. For example the error is also triggered by `fs.exists(pt)` and by `fs.setReplication()`.

Comment: You need to read, carefully, the error message. It tells you what is wrong: *InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: callId, status;*. So you're sending invalid data to the server. The problem is in what you send, not in how you send it.

Comment: @JB Nizet Yes I have **read** the error message. Multiple times. Over and over again. I don't even know what "Message" the error message is talking about. If you looked over my code that I included, you'd see that I have nothing that directly calls anything named "Message". I've got my debug working and can tell you that it's happening with any FileSystem message I try to call (i.e. it also happens with `fs.exists(pt)` or `fs.setReplication(pt, (short)1)`). I cannot find where this error is directly occurring though.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol between the HDFS client and the NameNode uses Google Protocol Buffers to serialize messages.  The error indicates that the message sent by the client did not contain all of the expected fields, so it is incompatible with the server.

This likely indicates that you are running a version of the HDFS client that is older than the version of the NameNode.  For example, the `callId` field was implemented in the feature tracked by Apache JIRA issue [HADOOP-9762](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9762) and shipped in Apache Hadoop 2.1.0-beta.  A client prior to that version would not have included `callId` in its messages, so it would be incompatible with a NameNode running 2.1.0-beta or later.

I suggest reviewing your client application to make sure that it is using the Hadoop client library version that matches the Hadoop cluster version.  From the stack trace, it appears that you are using the Cloudera distribution.  If so, then you'll likely have the most success by using the matching client library dependency version provided by Cloudera in their Maven repository.  See [Using the CDH 5 Maven Repository](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_vd_cdh5_maven_repo.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I belive hdfs using google protobuf library. And your client code seems to be using wrong (incompatible) version of protobuf. Try digging in this direction.